# Contact form 7 wordpress load new form on sent

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms, contact-form-7

I have 3 contact form 7 forms that I want to present to my visitor in sequence.
The first form is 'participate'. After it is sent successfully, I want to present the second form, 'invite', and hide the 'participate' form. The 'social' form will be presented last, with both the 'participate' and 'invite' forms hidden.
I am embedding the forms directly into my theme template. I will prefer a php solution...but I'm open to an solution that works. :-)

This could be a good plugin idea if one doesn't already exist.

```
<div id="invite" class="form-case">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="2743" title="Giveaway invite 1"]'); ?>
</div>
<div id="social" class="form-case">
<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="2746" title="Giveaway social 1"]'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually, it does already exist. Gravity Forms allows you to create multiple steps forms.

Comment: @user1724434, I was referring to a contact form 7 extension. I have over 27 forms set up using contact form 7 with mailchimp integrations and extensive CSS styling. It will be a BIG pain to migrate Gravity Forms at this point. :D

Comment: check out this plugin:https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-multi-step-module/

Comment: @bax, that extension doesn't function they way i need it to. it requires the creation of multiple pages instead of sequentially loading up multiple forms in the same page. It also only sends out an email at the final step. I need emails dispatched after each step. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Contact Form 7 Multi-Step Forms extension 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-multi-step-module/

Or if you want an email sent form every submission you can create 3 forms and add this in the additional settings section of CF7 `on_sent_ok: "location.replace('http://www.example.com');"` to forward from page 1 to 2 and so on.

To keep everything in one page, use `<iframe>` so that the first forms redirects to the second and so on, all within the iframe on the same page.

Comment: that extension doesn't function they way i need it to. it requires the creation of multiple pages instead of sequentially loading up multiple forms in the same page. It also only sends out an email at the final step. I need emails dispatched after each step. Thanks for the suggestion though.